# X11 automatically opening during Mac R session

Tags: r, macos, x11, xquartz

Mac OS X 10.9.5, R 3.2.3 (2015-12-10), XQuartz 2.7.8 (xorg-server 1.16.4)

I just updated X11 via http://www.xquartz.org/ so that I could install the diveRsity package (it wouldn't install without an X11 update and directed me to the xquartz website). The package now installs and is working fine.

However, X11 is opening everytime I open R (even if i don't require any packages) and, most annoyingly, every keyboard stroke I make when I'm inside the brackets of a function is running the wheel and flashing the stop button on the R console. This means that as I type, the console is constantly flashing. When I quit X11, R closes as well. Prior to the X11 update, there was no flashing and X11 did not open automatically when I ran R. I was still able to use quartz windows for plotting without the need to have X11 open in the background.

How can I open and use R without X11 opening automatically? Thank you.

Comment: Delete the hidden .Rdata file that is loading one of the packages that requires XQuartz.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the diveRsity library and reinstalled it. Now X11 only opens when I load that package, not every time.

Comment: In case anyone using RStudio is also looking for a possible solution, here is what I did: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/308#issuecomment-618038573